# Firebase ID token has incorrect "aud" (audience) claim

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin, google-app-engine-python

I have a frontend, which is hosted via Firebase. The code uses Firebase authentication and retrieves the token via `user.getIdToken()`. According to answers to similar questions that's the way to go.

The backend is written in Python, expects the token and verifies it using the firebase_admin SDK. On my local machine, I set `FIREBASE_CONFIG` to the path to `firebase-auth.json` that I exported from my project. Everything works as expected.

Now I deployed my backend via Google AppEngine. Here I configure `FIREBASE_CONFIG` as JSON string in the app.yaml. The code looks like this:

```
runtime: python37

env_variables:
    FIREBASE_CONFIG: '{
        "type": "service_account",
        "project_id": "[firebase-project-name]",
        ...
```

The backend logs the value of `FIREBASE_CONFIG` at startup. In the logs I can see the JSON string is there and `{` is the first character. So everything looks good to me. But if I retrieve the token from the client and try to validate it (same code, that is working locally) it get this error:

> Firebase ID token has incorrect "aud" (audience) claim. Expected
>   "[backend-appengine-project-name]" but got "[firebase-project-name]". Make sure the ID token
>   comes from the same Firebase project as the service account used to
>   authenticate this SDK.

Can somebody explain, what I'm missing and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The error message makes it sound like the user of your client app is signed into a different Firebase project than your backend is working with.  Taking the error message literally, the client is using "backend-appengine-project-name", but your backend is using "firebase-project-name".  Make sure they are both configured to use the same project using the same project ID.

Comment: No, the client is using "firebase-project-name", but the backend expects "backend-appengine-project-name". As I wrote, the backend is configured using the exported credentials from the firebase project. Locally it is working, but I don't get what's different in the deployed version.

Comment: I don't know if that's something we can debug for you, unless you're able to provide a MCVE that anyone can use to repro: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I think your `FIREBASE_CONFIG` is incorrect. I see the field `"type": "service_account"`, which is a field normally found in service account credentials, but never in `FIREBASE_CONFIG`. Also the project ID in `FIREBASE_CONFIG` must be spelt `projectId`.

Answer (score -2):

```
final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
    IdTokenResult idTokenResult = await user.getIdToken(refresh: true);
    print("userIdToken:" + idTokenResult.token);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.